# String comparison using Excel ODBC driver

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc

The following SQL query gives this error :

> "[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1."

```
Dim adoRS As New ADODB.Recordset

adoRS.Open "SELECT CStr(BOX) AS 'STRBOX',SLOT FROM [BIOSAMPLES$] WHERE STRBOX = '" & CStr(nBoxID) & "'" & " ORDER BY SLOT", adoConn
```

What is wrong?

Comment: do you literally want to pass "Cstr(Box)" to the db?  Shouldn't you evaluate this in vba first?

Comment: Hi. No, because ODBC Excel driver do not understand CAST or CONVERT functions but just CStr. The problem seems to be that the STRBOX alias is not found when the WHERE clause is evaluated.

Comment: Is this all of your code? Are you opening an `ADODB.Connection` first?

Comment: Hi. Yes of course. I just put that for the sake of brevity. I've found a workaround. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a workaround to this stupid Excel problem. This is my solution:

```
Dim adoRS As New ADODB.Recordset

adoRS.Open "SELECT BOX,SLOT FROM [BIOSAMPLES$] WHERE CStr('B' & BOX) = 'B" & CStr(nBoxID) & "'" & " ORDER BY SLOT", adoConn
```

Cheers.-